# Merging streams in a Bloc

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, rxdart

I've got a few streams in my bloc. I am not sure if this is a proper and correct approach because I am new to Flutter and Bloc pattern. 
But how can I merge the streams in the Bloc into one?

Any hints on the topic are welcome...

**My Bloc file**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

class WelcomeBloc {
  final _controller = PublishSubject<PageController>();
  final _page = PublishSubject<int>();
  final _lastPage = PublishSubject<bool>();

  Stream<dynamic> get combinedStream =>
      CombineLatestStream.list([getController, currentPage, isLastPage]);

  Stream<PageController> get getController => _controller.stream;
  Stream<int> get currentPage => _page.stream;
  Stream<bool> get isLastPage => _lastPage.stream;

  updatePage(int page) {
    _page.sink.add(page);
  }

  updatePageState(bool state) {
    _lastPage.sink.add(state);
  }

  dispose() {
    _controller.close();
    _page.close();
    _lastPage.close();
  }
}

final welcomeBloc = WelcomeBloc();
```

Consumer

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../../blocs/welcome_bloc.dart';
import './pages/page.dart';
import './pages/page2.dart';
import './pages/login.dart';

class ViewerWrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: welcomeBloc.combinedStream,
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          return PageView(
            children: <Widget>[
              Page1(),
              Page2(),
              Login(),
            ],
            onPageChanged: (page) {
              welcomeBloc.updatePage(page);
              print(snapshot.data._page);
              // welcomeBloc.updatePage(page + 1);
            },
            // controller: snapshot.data.getController,
          );
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by merge?

Comment: @AnirudhBagri Thanks for being here, man!) I mean that in my Bloc file I've got  three streams but in a StreamBuilder I can subscribe to one only stream. So, as I understand, I should merge them together so I can use it in my StreamBuilder. I tried to use combinedlatest but it returns null for me. I guess I'm doing something wrong there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Rx.combineLatest3` Like [this link](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxdart/blob/1ec9b582e5d3afa807f96393493100dd5fca4f96/test/streams/combine_latest_test.dart#L69)
to merge streams but as I understand from your code, it’s better to define a Model like this:

```dart
Class MyModel{

    PageController pageController;
    int currentPage;
    bool isLastPage;
...

}
```

And then have a single stream that works with it.

### Edit: applied model to code

I changed the code with two approaches.

**First One**

You can define a model and work with that model, so you don't need 3 different streams, this is OK if you always need the combined stream version and not each of the streams in any other places.

> I wrote code in one file.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

class MyModel {
  PageController pageController;
  int currentPage;
  bool isLastPage;

  MyModel({this.currentPage, this.pageController, this.isLastPage});
}

class WelcomeBloc {
  var _myModel = PublishSubject<MyModel>();

  Stream<MyModel> get getModel => _myModel.stream;

  // updatePage(int page) {
  //   _page.sink.add(page);
  // }

  // updatePageState(bool state) {
  //   _lastPage.sink.add(state);
  // }
  void updateModel(MyModel model) {
    _myModel.sink.add(model);
  }

  dispose() {
    _myModel.close();
  }
}

final welcomeBloc = WelcomeBloc();

class ViewerWrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<MyModel>(
        stream: welcomeBloc.getModel,
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<MyModel> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            MyModel model = snapshot.data;
            return PageView(
              children: <Widget>[
                Page1(),
                Page2(),
                Login(),
              ],
              onPageChanged: (page) {
                model.currentPage = page;
                welcomeBloc.updateModel(model);
                print(model.currentPage);
                // welcomeBloc.updatePage(page + 1);
              },
              controller: model.pageController,
            );
          }
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        });
  }
}
```

**Second one**

If you also need other streams in other places and so on, you can combine streams, you can combine them in any way you want, list, map, or a defined model, I used a model(MyModel).

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

class MyModel {
  PageController pageController;
  int currentPage;
  bool isLastPage;

  MyModel({this.currentPage, this.pageController, this.isLastPage});
}

class WelcomeBloc {
  final _controller = PublishSubject<PageController>();
  final _page = PublishSubject<int>();
  final _lastPage = PublishSubject<bool>();

  Stream<MyModel> get combinedStream =>
      Rx.combineLatest3(_page, _lastPage, _controller,
          (int page, bool isLast, PageController controller) {
        return MyModel(
          currentPage: page,
          isLastPage: isLast,
          pageController: controller,
        );
      });

  Stream<PageController> get getController => _controller.stream;
  Stream<int> get currentPage => _page.stream;
  Stream<bool> get isLastPage => _lastPage.stream;

  updatePage(int page) {
    _page.sink.add(page);
  }

  updatePageState(bool state) {
    _lastPage.sink.add(state);
  }

  dispose() {
    _controller.close();
    _page.close();
    _lastPage.close();
  }
}

final welcomeBloc = WelcomeBloc();

class ViewerWrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<MyModel>(
        stream: welcomeBloc.combinedStream,
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<MyModel> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            MyModel model = snapshot.data;

            return PageView(
              children: <Widget>[
                Page1(),
                Page2(),
                Login(),
              ],
              onPageChanged: (page) {
                welcomeBloc.updatePage(page);
                print(model.currentPage);
                // welcomeBloc.updatePage(page + 1);
              },
              controller: model.pageController,
            );
          }
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: If I got you right, this model will just combine three streams together, right? But I will need to have a mutual stream to use in my StreamBuilder/stream. It won’t be able to subscribe to it. What do you do when you’ve got a couple of streams in a bloc?

Comment: Sorry if my questions seem too silly) but I’m a bit puzzled here

Comment: No, it doesn't combine 3 stream, it group these information in one model and then inside one stream you can have theme all. I'll edit my answer for more details.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! But there is another problem with the combined stream. combineTheLatest3 awaits for all three streams to emit value. Before that it's null. But ok, that can be solved by initState in the stream Widget but apparently combineLatest3 or any other works like a zipStream. I haven't tried it in your snippet yet but it did as I played around with rxDart library.

Comment: Yes, that's true, for the very first time it needs all streams to have value, I guess You can use `Rx.forkJoin3`, [If an inner observable does not complete `forkJoin` will never emit a value](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin).

Comment: I forgot to mention it in the answer that for combining streams I usually get better performance by using `BehaviorSubject` because of it's nature.[(always returns the last value to every new/old subscriber)](https://www.didierboelens.com/2018/08/reactive-programming-streams-bloc/).

Comment: yeah, I usually use BehaviorSubject in JS ecosystem. It’s very useful since it emits the initial value. The only issue about it is that it keeps and emits the last value to all the subscribers. Thanks! I have never used forkjoin operator maybe that’s what I need.

Comment: Can you dart a glance  to some other my questions?

Comment:  Yes for sure!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61611230/get-updated-state-outside-a-widget-tree-with-redux 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61598767/didchangedependencies-hook-in-flutter-widget-includes-not-accurate-data-of-the-c

Comment: Can, you have a look at another question?) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61711139/mapeventtostate-triggers-one-time-only

Answer (score 1):

Don't think that is how it's done. Although if you wan to do it this way, try putting your stream builder as a child of another stream builder. But I won't recommend that way.

You don't listen to multiple streams from the same bloc, a good way would be to have a single stream per bloc architecture.

You could read more about providers, they are simpler than bloc and is recommended by the flutter community.

Comment: I am playing around with all kinds of patterns and data management systems like Provider, Redux and Bloc + Streams. I completely agree with you about Provider. I like it and it's really very simple. But Providers don't work with Streams and since I've worked with Angular and it's all about streams I'd like to try this way as well. It's better to know a couple of ways of how to reach of what you need. Many people recommended Bloc so I guess there must be a reason for that.So far I can see it's good for structuring the architecture.But It's confusing for me that you can use only one stream there

Comment: Maybe if you have a few minutes can you Dart a glance at these questions as well? ;) Flutter Community is not that talkative here :D - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61598767/didchangedependencies-hook-in-flutter-widget-includes-not-accurate-data-of-the-c